# SSRS Count Distinct Fields!B.value Where Fields!A.value =

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a report with two tables.  The first table is a list of clients, detailing each client that falls into one category of three with different items for each client.  The SQL joins up a client_table with the client_items table (there can be multiple items per client) the SQL results looks like so:

```
Type    ClientID    ItemID
A       1           1
A       3           1
A       3           2
B       2           1
B       4           3
C       5           2
```

My second table is going to return counts of the distinct ClientIDs from various combinations of the types:

- Total (A+B+C) - I've got this one figured out with `=CountDistinct(Fields!ClientID.Value,"datasource1")`
- Type B+C - Distinct ClientIDs where the type is B or C
- Type C - Distinct ClientIDs where the type is C

I hope that was clear, if not let me know what I need to add to clear it up.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`CountDistinct()` counts non-null values, so you could use an expression to null out those values you don't want to count and do something similar to your first value.

Type B+C:

```
=CountDistinct
(
  IIf
  (
    Fields!Type.Value = "B" or Fields!Type.Value = "C"
    , Fields!ClientId.Value
    , Nothing
  )
  , "datasource1"
)
```

Type C:

```
=CountDistinct
(
  IIf
  (
    Fields!Type.Value = "C"
    , Fields!ClientId.Value
    , Nothing
  )
  , "datasource1"
)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I came up with, just came back to answer it myself but ya beat me to it.  Thanks!  Aslo, well done understanding my explanation...  I knew the problem had a simple solution, but I figured that my inability to describe the problem was going to be my biggest hurdle.

Answer (score 2):

```
=Sum(CountDistinct(Fields!UserName.Value,"IssueDate7"))
```

Here Username is the row group and Issuedate7 is the column group

Regards

Mercy S