# SSRS Web ReportViewer CountDistinct Bug?

Tags: reporting-services, count, null, distinct

I have an SSRS report that I'm using in both a WebForm and a WinForm application using the ReportViewer control.  The report has several CountDistincts in a Tablix control, which displays counts by month.  My expression is: FormatNumber(CountDistinct(Fields!ClientID.Value), 0).  Some months have no data, but I want those months to have a column, so I insert a dummy record for that month with a NULL in the column that is being counted (ClientID).

In the WinForm application, this works just fine: the NULL value is not counted in the total, but in the WebForm viewer, the NULL is counted, so the Client count is always 1 when it should be 0 (since there was no data for that month).

I believe I'm using the latest version of the control: 11.0.3452.

Has anyone seen this issue or have any thoughts on how to deal with it?

Comment: looks like you need to set the Nulls to nothing.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14244368/ssrs-count-distinct-fieldsb-value-where-fieldsa-value

Comment: Thanks for your response!

Having to check every record and change a NULL to Nothing and THEN do a countdistinct would make this report unbearably slow.  It doesn't make sense to me that I should have to do this, either, since countdistinct is supposed to ignore NULLs and it works fine when viewing through WinForms.