# Overload Resolution Failed error when Iif expression has 2 criteria

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I need to use multiple criteria in a totals matrix and found what I thought could possibly help to solve my problem in 
[SSRS Count Distinct Fields!B.value Where Fields!A.value =](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14244368/ssrs-count-distinct-fieldsb-value-where-fieldsa-value).
I tried to convert it to count distinct project number values, only when the Milestone name contains "SD01" AND the Milestone Completed field is populated with a date.
I entered the following expression but when I previewed the matrix I got an error:

> Overload Resolution failed because no acceptable Iif accepts this number of arguments.

I was under the impression that 2 arguments were permitted.
Please could someone point me in the right direction, is my code rubbish, or am I trying the impossible?
Expression:

```
=CountDistinct
(
  IIf
  (
    Fields!MilestoneDateCompleted.Value >0 AND  
    Fields!MilestoneName.Value.Substring(5,4)="SD01",
    , Fields!ccx_projectnumber.Value
    , Nothing
  )
  , "DataSet1"
);
```

Comment: There is an uneeded semicolon at the end of your expression

Comment: Remove the comma after "SD01"

Comment: So there is, I do apologise.   Been working on it so long I couldn't see the wood for the trees. Comma Removed now and working well